# is there any conditions to use jqGrid on modal?

Tags: javascript, html, dialog, jqgrid, modal-dialog

I'm trying to use jqGrid on modal but it doesn't work even though it is exist on code when i look at the inspector. i just need simple table that shows data.
however it works when it's outside of modal-dialog().

```
***
```

> html

```
<div class="modal fade" id="addLkp05Modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" style="margin:auto;">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="addLkp05Modal_Label">제시외 건물 입력</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <table id="apprEtcListToggle">
                    </table>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary apprBtn" id="apprEtcList">평가제시외 목록</button>
                  <div id="apprEtcListCon">
                  </div>
                  <div class="row tbl_padd" id="tbl_modal_wrap" style="margin-left: 0;">
                    <table id="addLkp05Inputs">
                        <tr>
                            <th>용도</th>
                            <td><input type="text" name="UTIL" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>구조</th>
                            <td><input type="text" name="SHAPE" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>면적내용</th>
                            <td><input type="text" name="AREA" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>평가액</th>
                            <td><input type="text" name="GAM_AMT" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>비고</th>
                            <td><input type="text" name="BIGO" /></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn bg-blue-grey waves-effect btn_size" data-dismiss="modal" id="addLkp05Btn">추가</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

> js

```
    $("#apprEtcListToggle").jqGrid({
            width: 'auto',
            height: 'auto',
            datatype: "local",
            styleUI : 'Bootstrap',
            iconSet : 'Octicons',
            shrinkToFit :false,
            autowidth: true,
            multiselect: true,
            modal: true,
            colNames: ["기호", "용도", "구조", "면적", "단가", "감정평가액"],
            colModel : [
                { name: "BD_Sign", index: "BD_Sign", align: 'center', width:60 },
                { name: "BD_Use", index: "BD_Use", align: 'center' },
                { name: "BD_Structure", index: "BD_Structure", align: 'center' },
                { name: "EstiArea", index: "EstiArea", align: 'center' },
                { name: "AppliedUPrice", index: "AppliedUPrice", align: 'center' },
                { name: "BDApprasalVal", index: "BDApprasalVal", align: 'center' },
            ],
            beforeSelectRow: () => {
                $("#apprListToggle").jqGrid("resetSelection");
            },
            onSelectRow: (rowid) => {
            },
    });
    $("#apprEtcListToggle").jqGrid('setGridParam', { data : apprEtcItems }).trigger('reloadGrid');
***
it also works outside of modal. only if it comes inside of modal(class modal-dialog) it doesn't appear.
```

Answer (score 0):

We have write a article for this purpose again with example. You may look at [Guriddo Knowledge base here](http://guriddo.net/?kbe_knowledgebase=using-jqgrid-as-pop-up-selection)

Comment: I just look at the link you gave and thanks to reply on my question. however I'm afraid to say this is not what I wanted.
The problem is, if I use jqGrid on outside of modal, it's clearly appear on the screen but if i use it on modal, code is exist but not appear on the screen(on the modal). The code is exist in specific element if I look at the inspector but not appear on the screen like element is having "width:0".

Comment: I suppose you use a button or link to activate the modal so that it appear on the screen. In the example provided did you see how the modal is activated and the grid appear. You will need to edit the row and click on **sel** link (in the last column) to appear the modal with the grid.